# Django Rest Framework - Serializing Model Relationships

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have been working on this problem for a while now and cannot get to the bottom of what I'm doing wrong.
I am trying to add a many-to-many relationship between two models using Django REST framework using the PrimaryKeyRelatedField, but cannot get the relationship to save.

What the code I've got below does is save the newly created first_model item, but it does not save the relationship (if i view the relationship table it remains empty)

Any tips on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated!

Here is a snippet of the code I have:
Here is the views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def RiskCreate(request):
    serializer = First_ModelSerializer(data = request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        print("data is not valid")

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here are the models:

```
class First_Model(models.Model):

    Model_Title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank=True)
    Model_Descr = models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank=True)
    relationship = models.ManyToManyField(Second_Model)

class Second_Model(models.Model):
    Title_two = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    Descr_two = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
```

Here are is the serializer:

```
class First_ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relationship = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Risks
        fields = ('Model_Title', 'Model_Descr', 'relationship')
```

And here is how I'm passing the data to the view:

```
function addHazard(item){
        var url = baseurl + 'api/Create/'
        var ID = item.id
        var Model_Title = document.getElementById('Model_Title').value
        var Model_Descr = document.getElementById('Model_Descr').value
        fetch (url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'Model_Title':Model_Title, 'Model_Descr':Model_Descr, 'relationship': [{'id':ID}]})
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `read_only=True` in `relationship` field, [explanation in docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

simply remove it,

```
relationship = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True)
```